# How can I make Eula.java display Unicode?

Tags: java, android, unicode, eula

The Eula module from [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/DivideAndConquer/src/com/google/android/divideandconquer/Eula.java?r=93) works great but it doesn't display Unicode characters (e.g. ©) for some reason.

I know that AlertDialogs are perfectly capable of displaying Unicode characters, because I do so in other dialogs in my app.

The only difference I have been able to find between Eula's dialog and others is that the Eula.java dialog gets its string from a text file in the assets folder:

```
  private static CharSequence readEula(Activity activity) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open(ASSET_EULA)));
      String line;
      StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        buffer.append(line).append('\n');
      return buffer;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      return "";
    }
    finally {
      closeStream(in);
    }
  }
```

That text file displays all Unicode characters in Notepad++, so I can only suspect `InputStreamReader`, `BufferedReader` or `StringBuilder` doing something to the string on its way from the assets file to the AlertDialog.

How can I make Eula.java display Unicode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) the encoding of the source data; this class transcodes data to UTF-16 character data.

Comment: I tried this. It still doesn't work. See my comments below to @Joachim Sauer. +1 anyway.

Comment: @ef2011 - if the text appears correctly in Notepad++, use the _Encoding_ menu to see what encoding is being used. If it is "ANSI", then it is a Windows encoding (which one depends on the OS.) In your hex editor the code point U+00A9 (©) has the following values in respective encodings: UTF-8 `C2 A9`; windows-1252 `A9`; ISO-8859-1 `A9`.

Comment: You were right on the money. It turns out Notepad++ shows ANSI and once I changed the 2nd parameter to `InputStreamReader()` from "utf-8" to "ISO-8859-1" it works now. Wow. +1 again and accepting. Thank you!

Comment: @ef2011 - ISO-8859-1 is not the same as Windows [ANSI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/31/144893.aspx). If you are developing on Western European system, it will be windows-1252 (aka [Cp1252](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)). See the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964654) for a list of "ANSI" encodings. In any case, I advise you to save the file as UTF-8 instead - this is the 21st century.

Answer (score 2):

In "normal" Java the [single-argument `InputStreamReader` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) uses the platform default encoding.

Android has defined this [*slightly* different](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream%29), saying

> This constructor sets the character converter to the encoding specified in the `"file.encoding"` property and falls back to ISO 8859_1 (ISO-Latin-1) if the property doesn't exist.

So setting `file.encoding` to the encoding used in the asset (probably UTF-8) might just do the trick.

Alternatively (if you can edit it), just change the constructor call to the [two-argument version](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) and specify the correct encoding this way.

Comment: I tried calling the two-argument version: With either "UTF16" or "UTF-16" it displays "Chinese" (original text in English!). With either "UTF8" or "UTF-8" it displays exactly as before: Correct English text with the © turned into a question mark symbol. What's happening?

Comment: Looking at the original file via a Hex editor, it looks like a UTF-8 file... I still don't understand why "UTF8" or "UTF-8" wouldn't work.